# Check how many same items a list contains

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a list that contains names of Unity gameobjects.

I would like to have a method that I can call with the one of the names in the list, and it to return how many of that name is in the list.

How could I make this?

Comment: There are several ways to do that. For example, you could use a For Each loop to expect each item in the list and keep a running count of matches. Or you could use LINQ. If you don't know how to do either of those you should investigate the For Each loop, since it is so fundamental to many things in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Linq its ultra easy:

suppose you have a List of string named list and search for Name, so you could write:

```
using System.Linq;
:

private int Count(List<string> list, string NameSearch)
{
    return list.Count(n => n == NameSearch);
}
```

Comment: The code example does a great job of explaining how it works, but I just want to point out that this `int Count(List<string> list, string NameSearch)` method shouldn't really be created in actual code as it's just an empty wrapper around the existing LINQ method.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a List called namesList, you can make a for-loop and check for each item if it exists inside this list and count how many time you found it.

```
  public int countNameOccurance(string name, List<string> namesList) {
           int count = 0;

           for(int i=0; i < namesList.Count(); i++){
               if( namesList[i] == name){//check if the item exists in the list
               count++; 
               }
            }
          return count;
}
```